# Custom Button - Close the Status for Cases in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, case, button, custom, status

I am struggling with the following task:

**1) I need to create a custom button "Close the status", that closes the status for the Case and**

**2) it should be located at the same position as on the picture below (location of the Close the ticket).**

[image]

I have tried different things:

1. I created a quick action that just updates the record with a pre-defined value of the Status - Closed. It works, but it is located in the Chatter. I disabled the Feed Tracking for Case, Quick Actions moved to the Highlight Panel, as I wanted... but the Chatter disappeared, which we still need to  have.
2. I tried to create a Custom Button with a **Display Type - Detail Page Button, Behavior: Execute Java Script, with a Content Source: OnClick JavaScript**  with the following code:

   `{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
   var p = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
   p.id = "{! Case.Id }"; 
   p.Status = "Closed"; 
   result = sforce.connection.update([p]); 
   location.reload(true);`

This code works good and it changed the status of the case in one click, but...only in Classic. I don't see it in Lightning :(

3. I tried to create a custom button with **Display Type - Detail Page Button, Content Source - URL** and with: `/{!Case.Id}/s?retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}&cas7=Closed`

   Closes the status but only in Classic.

All custom buttons I put into the page layout for the custom button placeholder, but I don't see them at the Lightning Experience at all.

I am Beginner in Apex and Visualforce pages, but I have a feeling maybe it is possible to create a custom button with Apex or Visualforce.

If someone had the same problem with the Close the Status button, could you please tell me the direction? Is it possible to create a custom button with Apex or Visualforce? What are the steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of overlapping challenges here.

- **JavaScript buttons are not supported in Lightning**, so that option is out.
- **Cases** have [special behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=0) in Lightning Experience regarding placement of Quick Actions:

  > When feed tracking is enabled for cases or work orders, the page-level action menu on those records contains only custom buttons and supported standard buttons. Quick actions appear on the Chatter tab.

If you *must* have this button shown in the button bar on the Case record page, and you *must* have feed tracking turned on, I believe only code-based solutions remain available to you.

Those would be either

- Developing a Visualforce-page button, where I think you may find getting the user experience just right a bit challenging.
- Developing a Lightning component that can be placed on a custom Lightning Record Page.

I would prefer the latter, myself, for a fully-native Lightning experience. However, I don't believe there's a way to do either of these without writing Apex + either Visualforce or Lightning JavaScript.